# In-content [tag]'s have a CSS, margin issue

Tags: bug, design

Through out the whole site, where `[tag:something]` is used, or where framework inherits the same behavior, there is a problem with CSS.

Check this[mechanics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanics) (before the tag, the letter s is hid, but the spacing after the tag is enormous).

I see in CSS, it lacks `margin-left` property:

```
margin: 2px 15px 6px 0!important;
```

That translates to:

```
margin-top: 2px !important;
margin-right: 15px !important;
margin-bottom: 6px !important;
margin-left: 0 !important;
```

What it should be though, is something like this:

```
margin: 2px 8px 6px 8px!important;
```

Giving some margin to left, and subtracting from right, resulting in a very nice looking tag.